# How do you link a field in a table to the sum of a field in another table?

Tags: sql-server

Please I use Sql Server
I have the Quantity field in the Items table equal to the sum of the Quantity fields in the Stocks table.
Is there a way to do this automatically in?
[image]

Comment: Stocks.Quintity might lead to some problems....

Comment: You might be better off with a `VIEW` for this, if I am honest; otherwise you'll be needing `TRIGGER`s or you could use procedures to handle all your DML statements so it can adjust the values accordingly.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an indexed view to hold the aggregation, which means that the server will maintain the view whenever there is any modification to the base tables. This removes the possibility of update anomalies.

```sql
CREATE VIEW vwTotalStock AS

SELECT i.ItemId, i.ItemName, SUM(s.Quantity) TotalQuantity
FROM dbo.Items i
JOIN dbo.Stocks s ON s.ItemId = i.ItemId
GROUP BY
    i.ItemId, i.ItemName;

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vwTotalStock ON dbo.vwTotalStock (ItemId);
```